# Retrieve aggregated data as per user time zone

Tags: postgresql, performance, timestamp, timezone

I have a postgres database that has all of its data in UTC. If I need to show any data or aggregation for a single day, I can just convert the local time to UTC and use that in my query.

However, now I have to implement a graph that shows months of data aggregated for each day. For example, consumed calories for each day for 6 months that are calculated from the food logs added by the user everyday.

The problem is that any log added at 9AM (as breakfast) will be stored in the previous day if the user is in any time zone that is more than 9 hours ahead of GMT. And it will not be included in the result.

My initial thought was to aggregate over 24 hour intervals from the start time but that is not a good idea for when DST is applied or removed. A single day with 23 or 25 hours throws all the subsequent data off by 1 hour.

On the client-side, I have access to the user's time zone. The solution I have in my mind is to send the time zone along with the request so all rows can be checked with a timestamp `AT TIME ZONE 'clients-time-zone'`.

This seems like a common enough problem and I could not find any good resources on it. Is this a good idea or is there a better approach than this?

For context, the app is in Flutter and the backend is built on top of Supabase which uses Postgres. There is no API layer in the middle as I use DB Functions (Stored Procedures) to get all required data.

Comment: Yes, you have to store for each user for each consumption the time zone. Because people also travel or move to different time zones.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I dont think I need to store the time zone for each log since UTC is always going to stay consistent wherever you are. If the user travels to a new zone, only their local time changes. Therefore, the number of calories consumed in a day may change because their local time is different. This is acceptable to me as it is not possible to avoid it.

Please let me know if I am thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: You know way more about your business, then I do ;-) But I do notice that traveling between time zones results in a different eating pattern: A very long day with additional meals or a short one where I skip a meal. And if you don't change the time zone, having breakfast at 23:00 is a little strange, just like having diner at 03:00 at night. This breakfast, it that at 23:00 PST or 08:00 CET?

Comment: @FrankHeikens You are right. It is a little strange but I think this is better for consistency? What do you suggest? Saving the user's timezone with each log creates more problems for aggregation. What standard do I use in that case?

Comment: If you were to store the timezone in which each log was created you'd use the same aggregation provided by Laurenz Abe, it's just instead of `Europe/Vienna` coming from the user's settings it would come from the log. I think this is technically "the right way" since if I move from Japan to London it shouldn't change my historical calories per day, but it may not be worth it depending on your user profile (how often do people move? how often do people look at their very old data?)

Comment: I am not really concerned about people moving. Whatever approach I choose, I want to be sure that it does not produce inaccurate data. If I save the tz in the timestamp, how would that change the aggregation. The aggregation (total kcal consumed per day in this context) would need to happen in one timezone which should be the user's current timezone preferably. Imagine the user spends 6 months in one place and then moves to a place that is 1 hour behind. Should all of the old data be aggregated with the new timezone meaning that all new aggregations are off by 1 hour? Is that the best UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dates are stored in column `t`, which is of type `timestamp without time zone` and contains UTC data, and the client is in time zone `Europe/Vienna`, aggregate like this:

```
GROUP BY CAST (t AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna' AS date)
```

The first `AT TIME ZONE` converts `t` to an absolute timestamp, the second `AT TIME ZONE` converts it to what a wall clock in Vienna would show at that time, and the type cast truncates it do the date.

Comment: I have tried this way and it works just fine. I am concerned whether this is the most optimised way. Perhaps I am wrong and this is the ONLY way?

Comment: I think it is the best way. It is that complicated because you store UTC timestamps in a `timestamp without time zone` rather than using `timestamp with time zone` in the database. That would have saved you the first conversion.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would a query like that go if I start saving the timezone too? I thought saving timezone like that would not be useful. 

Lets say a user goes from California to Vienna after adding a log in California and then one in Vienna. If the log was added in California at 8pm, I would expect it to appear at 4am in their in-app calendar in Vienna. Therefore it would become a part of the next day's total calories consumed.

Comment: I was not talking about saving the time zone. `timestamp with time zone` does *not* save the time zone. It is an "absolute time". As `timestamp with time zone`, 8pm in California is identical to 4am in Vienna. They are the same on disk.

Comment: Hmmm. I thought there was a data type called `timestamptz` that can also store the offset. The idea being that you save the timestamp in UTC but with the offset. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. `timestamptz` is identical to `timestamp with time zone`, and it doesn't store an offset or a time zone (even though it looks like it at first glance).